Render a gif/mp4 image in blender
I want to render an animation/scene with a gif/mp4 playing but it doesn't show up in my scene. How can I get it to render?
Screenshot:

File: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/30a7901a67e6ea148b6f35803151433020240515130420/38ff4bd3f51548f47169fdcc581ca0fa20240515130433/978360
Thanks

Of course it is not showing up, it is an Empty set up as a reference image. Empties are not visible in render. You have to put the video as texture on a real plane object to render it. So instead of adding it in the scene with Add > Image > Reference use Image > Images as Planes.

This helps. Thank you Gordon.
